# How to extract string from raw data file (stuck)

Tags: regex, perl

I have a raw data text file and I am writing a perl script to extract a string from it. I am trying to get the computer name where the result would only be `UFLEX-06` however, I am getting `Computer Name: UFLEX-06` (with the tab spacing at the back of `Computer Name`).

This is what the text file contains:

`Computer Info:
    Computer Name: UFLEX-06
    Computer is external to Teradyne.
    Computer IP Address(es):`

This is what I've done so far in my perl script:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $filename = 'IGXLEventLog.3.17.2015.20.25.12.625.log';
open(my $fn, '<', $filename) or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";

our %details;

while(my $row = <$fn>)
{
    chomp $row;

    if($row =~ /Computer Name:/i)
    {
        my $cp_line;
        do
        {
            $cp_line .= $row;
        }while($row !~ /Computer Name:/);

    #Remove
    $cp_line =~ /Computer Name:/s;

    my @String = split(/Computer Name:/, $cp_line);

    #Assigning array elements to hash array
    $details{cp_line} = $String[0];

    print $details{cp_line};
    }
}
```

I'm new to Perl so do pardon me if there are any obvious mistakes. My idea was to use `split` so that I can remove the `Computer Name:`. Any help on this?

Comment: Your remove line needs "=~  s//" to do the replacement. Don't use split. Try the (.*) trick as answered, the matched name is stored in $0...

Comment: The `(.*)` doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really don't follow what you are trying to do with your own code, but this is all that is necessary

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $filename = 'IGXLEventLog.3.17.2015.20.25.12.625.log';

open my $fh, '<', $filename or die "Could not open file '$filename': $!";

while ( <$fh> ) {
    if ( /Computer Name:\s*(\S+)/i ) {
        print $1, "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Ahh this was what I was looking for. My bad, I thought too far ahead that I made it complicated. If you don't mind, can you explain what's $1?

Comment: `$1` contains the contents of the first *capture* (parenthesised expression) in the regex. In this case I have captured all non-space characters after `Computer Name: `

Comment: Thank you. +1 for a simple explanation as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex with capturing groups like this:

```
Computer Name: (.*)
```

And then grab the content from the group

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/nU7oZ5/1)**

I'm not good at Perl but I think you can use below code and adapt it to your needs:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $filename = 'IGXLEventLog.3.17.2015.20.25.12.625.log';
open(my $fn, '<', $filename) or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";

our %details;

while(my $row = <$fn>)
{
    chomp $row;

    if($row =~ m/Computer Name: (.*)/)
    {   
         print $1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried as you suggested,  this just returns a value `1`. Still trying out other ways.