# Stopping regex at the first match, it shows two times

Tags: regex, perl, match

I am writing a perl script and I have a simple regex to capture a line from a data file. That line starts with `IG-XL Version:`, followed by the data, so my regex matches that line.

```
if($row =~/IG-XL Version:\s(.*)\;/)
{
    print $1, "\n";
}
```

Let's say `$1` prints out `9.0.0`. That's my desired outcome. However in another part of the **same** data file also has a **same** line `IG-XL Version:`. $1 now prints out two of the data `9.0.0`.

I only want it to match the first one so I can only get the one value. I have tried `/IG-XL Version:\s(.*?)\;/` which is the most suggested solution by adding   a `?` so it'll be `.*?` but it still outputs two. Any help?

EDIT:

The value of `$row` is:

```
Current IG-XL Version: 8.00.01_uflx (P7); Build: 11.10.12.01.31
Current IG-XL Version: 8.00.01_uflx (P7); Build: 11.10.12.01.31
```

The desired value I want is `8.00.01_uflx (P7)` which I did get, but two times.

Comment: What is the value of `$row`

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do this while reading the file line by line is to keep a status flag that records whether you have already found that pattern. But if you are storing the data in a hash, as you were in [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30746611), then it won't matter as you will just overwrite the hash element with the same value

```
if ( $row =~ /IG-XL Version:\s*([^;]+)/ and not $seen_igxl_vn ) {
    print $1, "\n";
    $seen_igxl_vn = 1;
}
```

Or, if the file is reasonably small, you could read the whole thing into memory and search for just the first occurrence of each item

I suggest you should post a question showing your complete program, your input data, and your required output, so that we can give you a complete solution rather than seeing your problem bit by bit

Comment: Hmm I see, alright I'll post the whole thing if I really can't seem to find any other way. It's all in bits and pieces because I really want to try this myself, with a little help of course so do pardon me. I think you're right, I'll post up my main problem so that it'll be easier for everyone to understand.

Comment: There, I have posted and summarized my problems.