# Extracting data from log file into Perl hash

Tags: regex, perl, hash

I have a four log files. Each log file is in the same format so let's focus on one.

In each log file I have to extract information such as `Computer Name` and such. I won't post the log file here because it has over 46,000 lines.

My main goal in the end is that, once this information is extracted, I would store it in a hash. These hashes would be later used for an insert statement into a database table.

What I have done so far is this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $filename = 'IGXLEventLog.3.17.2015.20.25.12.625.log';
open(my $fn, '<', $filename) or die "Could not open file '$filename': $!";

our %details;

while ( my $row = <$fn> ) {
    chomp $row;

    if ( $row =~ /Computer Name:\s*(\S+)/i ) {
        print $1, "\n";
    }

    if ( $row =~/Operating System:\s*(.*)/i ) {
        print $1, "\n";
    }

    if ( $row =~/IG-XL Version:\s(.*?)\;/ ) {
        print $1, "\n";  
    }
}
```

#### Problem 1

I have no problem extracting the computer name and operating system from the log file. However, `IG-XL Version` in the log file occurs twice. So what I'm getting from printing `$1` is:

```
8.00.01_uflx (P7)
8.00.01_uflx (P7)
```

The original records are

```
Current IG-XL Version: 8.00.01_uflx (P7); Build: 11.10.12.01.31
Current IG-XL Version: 8.00.01_uflx (P7); Build: 11.10.12.01.31
```

So as you can see what I've managed to isolate the data that I want, but I get two results. My main objective now is to solve how to only get the first match.

Any help on this? Is there anything I am doing wrong? Please let me know.

#### Problem 2

This is problem is not my focus yet, but will be after I solve the first one. In the log file, there's a section where data is structured like this:

```
2.0  HSD-U       664-999-01 c301036 1251-A 5445
      ChanBoard0    233-455-00 c303bb6 1521-A 5445
      ChanBoard1    321-493-00 c303496 1321-A 5445
6.0   DC-07       888-375-02 0C31F8F1 1330-A 5445
    aka: 604-375-00
      DC-07       123-456-01 0C6203EF 1150-A 5445
    aka: 939-420-00
7.0   DC-07       613-493-00 c303496 1321-A 5445
    aka: 466-456-65
      DC-07       613-493-00 c303496 1321-A 5545
```

Notice there are digits (not to be treated as decimals) on the left-hand side such as `2.0`, `6.0`, `7.0` and so on. (Some other digits for example would be `1.4`, `5.60`, `57.58`.)

In this section of the string, I want to get only the first line according to the digits. So for `2.0` I would only pick up the line `2.0 HSD-U       664-999-01 c301036 1251-A 5445` and ignore the lines without numbers.

In this line, I want to get the fields `2.0` and `HSD-U` separately, and assign those two to a separate hash each.

So I need to extract a total of four types of different data, with the last type being the one that has the most pieces.

EDIT: What I did according to Borodin's answer

```
while(<$fn>)
{
    if ( /Computer Name:\s*(\S+)/i ) {
        $details{comp_name} //= $1;
        print $details{comp_name}, "\n";
    }
    elsif ( /Operating System:\s*(.*)/i ) {
        $details{op_sys} //= $1;
        print $details{op_sys}, "\n";
    }
    elsif ( /IG-XL Version:\s*([^;]*)/i ) {
        $details{igxl_vn} //= $1;
        print $details{igxl_vn}, "\n";
    }
    elsif ( /^([\d.]+)\s+(\S+)/ ) {
        $details{slot} //= $1;
        $details{name} //=$2;
        print $details{slot}, "\n", $details{name};
    }
}
```

My output:

```
UFLEX-06
Windows XP Service Pack 3
8.00.01_uflx (P7)
8.00.01_uflx (P7)    <-Duplicated
HSD-U2.0             <-Duplicated
HSD-U2.0             <-Duplicated
HSD-U2.0             <-Duplicated
HSD-U2.0             <-Duplicated
HSD-U2.0             <-Duplicated
HSD-U2.0             <-Duplicated
HSD-U8.00.01_uflx (P7) <-Weird line
```

This expected output is what I desire only up till the 3rd line.

An expected one would be:

```
UFLEX-06
Windows XP Service Pack 3
8.00.01_uflx (P7)
2.0
HSD-U
5.0
Gigabit
6.0
MattersNot
7.9
MatterMatter
15.20
Knnccb
```

EDIT 2: @Borodin Both as strings. In fact all as strings. What I am going to do is that for all these values, I will be inserting them into a table in my database where by I would create an SQL file with just the text: `INSERT INTO TABLE1(cp_name, os, version, slot, slot_name) values('UFLEX-06', 'Windows XP dot dot', '8.0.0_uflx', '2.0', 'HSD-U')`. This is just to show for a better understanding.

There would be a lot of `slots` in this `cp_name`. Just take it as a computer. There would be 4 ram slots. Each ram card would have a different name. The name or rather a way to identify which card is at which slot would be let's say the ram name is EatYou. That ram card is at slot 3. So I have to insert into the database all the details other than the ram name and ram slot number which would be the different one.

Back to the main point, that's why I'm trying to find a simple way to do this by assigning each value to a hash array so that when I create the sql file it would be easy for me to assign the insert values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would write it like this. Using an explicit variable for the file records just makes more noise so I've used Perl's default `$_`

The expression `$details{comp_name} //= $1` etc. assigns the hash element only if it doesn't already have a value

You didn't make it clear how you wanted the dotted decimals stored in your hash, so I've used the first field as a key and the second as a hash

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $filename = 'IGXLEventLog.3.17.2015.20.25.12.625.log';
open my $fh, '<', $filename or die "Could not open file '$filename': $!";

my %details;

while ( <$fh> ) {

    if ( /Computer Name:\s*(.*\S)/i ) {
        $details{comp_name} //= $1;
    }
    elsif (/Operating System:\s*(.*\S)/i ) {
        $details{op_sys} //= $1;
    }
    elsif (/IG-XL Version:\s*([^;]*)/ ) {
        $details{igxl_vn} //= $1;
    }
    elsif ( /^([\d.]+)\s+(\S+)/ ) {
        $details{$1} //= $2;
    }
}

use Data::Dump;
dd \%details;
```

**output**

```
{
  "2.0"       => "HSD-U",
  "6.0"       => "DC-07",
  "7.0"       => "DC-07",
  "comp_name" => "UFLEX-06",
  "igxl_vn"   => "8.00.01_uflx (P7)",
  "op_sys"    => "Windows XP Service Pack 3",
}
```

Comment: Ohh, for the dotted decimals I would be storing them as a string.

Comment: @hzq: Yes, but there are several of them (so it would take more than a single hash element) and you presumably want to relate the second column to the first somehow

Comment: I don't understand your answer though. Why are you using `elsif`? Wouldn't that only get `Computer  Name: ` and ignore the rest because `Computer Name: ` is the first match? What I want to get is all 4 of the pieces of data from `Computer Name: `, `Operating System: `, `IG-XL Version: `, `the digit and the name`. From what I understand, this would only output `Computer Name: ` because that's the one that occurs first in the log file.

Comment: @hzq: Have you tried it? That `if` statement is inside the `while` loop so it's being applied to every line in the file. Presumably there's only one item of information per line? Rather than saying the input file is too big and so showing us nothing, it would be best to create a minimal example of your input that we can test against, together with the result you want from it

Comment: Yes, I've tried it.  It outputs nothing though. I'll edit the question to grab a section of the log file to show you what I mean.

Comment: @hzq: Have you tried it since my comment? I had some spaces that shouldn't be there and updated it. And it won't output anything - it's simply building a hash as you requested

Comment: Ohh right, didn't notice you didn't print out the values. Let me print the outputs

Comment: Okay I've added a dump statement to show the contents of the hash it builds and run it against your data. My input datya is a combination of the two chunks that you show

Comment: Ahh yes. Okay now it's close. If you saw what I commented at @Dmitry 's post I changed the regex to `^(\S+.)+\s+(\S+)` but that's a wrong match. The current one you have provided(thank you) `/^([\d.]+)\s+(\S+)/` makes the digits such as `2.0` as the name of the hash array. Now what's that's  to do is to actually I want to get `2.0` and `HSD-U` together as a line __first__, from there that's where you saw in one of my questions I tried to do a `split`. I want to then `split` the lnie `2.0 `HSD-U` into `2.0` and `HSD-U`. Then I would assign each to a hash array. An help on this?

Comment: @hzq: They're already split into two fields in `$1` and `$2`. What I don't know is how you want to store them. How about an example?

Comment: @hzq: Your output is only duplicated because you've added print statements. If what you want is a hash then you must dump the resultant `%details` structure as I have done to see what has been collected. You also haven't specified how you want multiple `slot` and `name` values handled

Comment: I'll edit it in the question, I ran out of word count.

Comment: @hzq: You're still missing the point and not dumping the hash. For example, your `INSERT INTO` has only five values `cp_name`, `os`, `version`, `slot`, `slot_name` but there are *multiple* values of `slot` and `slot_name`. So you can't put all that information into a single hash or a single database record and you need to specify how you want to handle them

Comment: Hmm I understand what you mean. So to put multiple/different information in I need to dump the hash? What should I do after that?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by handling them though, you mean how am I going to use them or?

Comment: @hzq: No, you need to dump the hash to see what values the code is putting into it. Your `print` statements make it look as if there are multiple duplicates when there aren't. What I mean about handling the slot information is how are you going to write it into a database table with five columns? Each computer has one name, OS, and version, but a variable number of slot/name pairs. If there's only room for one such pair in your table then where are you putting the rest? There are a number of solutions but you need to say what you have in mind, if anything. Does this table already exist?

Comment: Alright I did the dump and the values are correct. That's dump would be counted as one row in the table. As for the slot information, one row would have a __different slot no. but can have the same name__ .So let's say the first row is `UFLEX-06`, `Windows`, `9.0.0`, `2.0`, `HSD-U`. The second row would be `UFLEX-06`, `Windows`, `9.0.0`, `5.0`, `HSD-U`. So as you can see the slot number is different, the slot name would have duplicates but there are different names as well. Slot number would be called as they say `unique`. And yes I have a dummy table created if you would like I could show you

Comment: Then about the handling I am going to use insert statements. So every time I want to insert a different slot I would use another insert statement. If I have 10 different slots I would use 10 different statements.

Comment: @hzq: Okay so any one system has multiple table rows with the same values for `cp_name`, `os`, and `version`, but a different `slot` and `slot_name` pair in each. That should work although it's not ideal as it's best not to have the same data duplicated in multiple places. If, for instance, you wanted to change the name of a computer, you would have several records to modify and would have to do it inside a transaction. It may well be good enough for you as it is though. I don't know if I shall be able to help much tomorrow as my main computer's system disk has died and I only have a tablet

Comment: Ahh it's okay! I've found a way how to include all the different `slot` and `slot_name`. I've made a global array and instead of `$details{$1} //= $2;` in your answer, I did a `push @matches, [$1, $2];` so that for every one that was matched I am able to assign it in `@matches`. Now I can move on to the next part of my work. Thank you, you've really been a great help. I marked your answer in the prev question as well. Again, thanks a lot.

Comment: @hzq: I was going to suggest something like that, but you should push it onto a hash element instead, with `push @{ $details{slot} }, [ $1, $2 ];`

Comment: Ohh I see, just tried that. I did `push @{ $details{slot} }, [ $1 ]` and `push @{ $details{slot_name} }, [ $2 ]` just to separate them. One question, how do I get index 0 ? If I were to print would it just be `$details{slot_name} [0]`? Cause when I print that I get `ARRAY(0x8750d0)`, how do I get the string instead?

Comment: You should put them together in a single array as I wrote. It's the same as you had for your `@matches` array! If you go for that then `$details{slot}[0]` is the first slot, with the number in `$details{slot}[0][0]` and the name in `$details{slot}[0][1]`. The info for the second slot is in `$details{slot}[1]` etc.

Comment: Ahh I see. Alright last of all, there's one thing that I was puzzled about before at the start. Why do you use `elsif` instead of just `if`? Because I don't understand why it is that way.

Comment: @hzq: Because that way it stops testing once it has found a match. Any one line of the file can contain only one type of information, so once one has been found there's no point in also testing for the rest. Gotta sleep now -- it's 2:30am!

Comment: Once you're awake, it'd be great if you could help me out in my other question. :)

Answer (score 0):

The first question has been already answered there: [Stopping regex at the first match, it shows two times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30748709/stopping-regex-at-the-first-match-it-shows-two-times)

As for the second, you need to use the start anchor (`^`) immediately followed by some digits and dots:

```
if($row =~/^[\d\.]+\s+(\S+)/)
{
    print $1, "\n";  
}
```

Here's how this regex works: https://regex101.com/r/vY7aL6/1

Comment: For the second problem, yes thank you for that. I have modified the expression to be `^(\S+.)+\s+(\S+)` because now I want the digits as well. As for the first problem, yes I tried that at my previous question and it didn't work but I didn't want to continue the discussion there so I've decided to post a whole new question as suggested by @Borodin . I am still currently searching(google) on how to solve the first. There are many suggested solutions, but they don't seem to cater to mine.

Comment: Hmm, I'm surprised that @Borodin's suggestion did't work for you, it definitely should, I believe. Anyway, this `//=` approach he's proposed for this question is even more beautiful. I've voted for it.