# Iterating through a array of hashes in a hash that has multiple indexes

Tags: arrays, perl, loops, hash, hashmap

I am currently writing a perl script that has a few hashes that containing:
(Do not take this as lines of codes, it's just to show/explain)

```
$details{tester_name} is "UFLEX-06"
$details{op_sys} is "Windows"
$details{igxl_vn} is "8.00.01_uflx (P7)"
$details{slot} -> see below for details
$details{board_name} -> see below for details
```

Now in $details{slot} I have multiple indexes that contain a value each.

```
$details{slot} [0] has "2"
$details{slot} [1] has "5"
```

and so on. **$details{slot} has the same number of indexes as $details{board_name}**.

Now I want to iterate through this **but according to $details{slot}**.

What I have done so far which iterates through **%details only**:

```
foreach my $key(keys %details)
{
    print {$fh} "INSERT INTO TesterDeviceMatrix.TBL_TESTER_INFO"
    ."(tester_name, operating_system , version, board_name , config , date_modified ) "
    ."VALUES ('$details{tester_name}', '$details{op_sys}', '$details{board_name}', "
    ."'$details{igxl_vn}', '$details{slot}', '$timestamp');\n";
}
```

But what I would like to do is something like

```
foreach my $key(keys %details{slot}) -> or %details{board_name}
{
    print {$fh} "INSERT INTO TesterDeviceMatrix.TBL_TESTER_INFO"
    ."(tester_name, operating_system , version, board_name , config , date_modified ) "
    ."VALUES ('$details{tester_name}', '$details{op_sys}', '$details{board_name}', "
    ."'$details{igxl_vn}', '$details{slot}', '$timestamp');\n";
}
```

I know this is wrong but it is just to show my idea of it.

Output I am getting now is:

```
INSERT INTO TBL_TESTER_INFO(tester_name, operating_system , version, board_name , config , date_modified ) VALUES ('UFLEX-06', 'Windows XP', 'VirtualDSPBrd', '8.00.01_uflx (P7)', '66.0', '2015-06-11 11:15:33');
INSERT INTO TBL_TESTER_INFO(tester_name, operating_system , version, board_name , config , date_modified ) VALUES ('UFLEX-06', 'Windows XP', 'VirtualDSPBrd', '8.00.01_uflx (P7)', '66.0', '2015-06-11 11:15:33');
INSERT INTO TBL_TESTER_INFO(tester_name, operating_system , version, board_name , config , date_modified ) VALUES ('UFLEX-06', 'Windows XP', 'VirtualDSPBrd', '8.00.01_uflx (P7)', '66.0', '2015-06-11 11:15:33');
INSERT INTO TBL_TESTER_INFO(tester_name, operating_system , version, board_name , config , date_modified ) VALUES ('UFLEX-06', 'Windows XP', 'VirtualDSPBrd', '8.00.01_uflx (P7)', '66.0', '2015-06-11 11:15:33');
INSERT INTO TBL_TESTER_INFO(tester_name, operating_system , version, board_name , config , date_modified ) VALUES ('UFLEX-06', 'Windows XP', 'VirtualDSPBrd', '8.00.01_uflx (P7)', '66.0', '2015-06-11 11:15:33');
```

The above output has 5 lines which because there are 5 hashes. However what I desire is **8 lines with values according to their indexes**, as there are 8 indexes for `$details{slot}` which means there also 8 indexes for `$details{board_name}`.

An example of my desired output would be (notice value difference and 8 lines):

```
INSERT INTO TBL_TESTER_INFO(tester_name, operating_system , version, board_name , config , date_modified ) VALUES ('UFLEX-06', 'Windows XP', 'abcBrd', '8.00.01_uflx (P7)', '2.0', '2015-06-11 11:15:33');
INSERT INTO TBL_TESTER_INFO(tester_name, operating_system , version, board_name , config , date_modified ) VALUES ('UFLEX-06', 'Windows XP', 'VqwelDSPBrd', '8.00.01_uflx (P7)', '5.0', '2015-06-11 11:15:33');
INSERT INTO TBL_TESTER_INFO(tester_name, operating_system , version, board_name , config , date_modified ) VALUES ('UFLEX-06', 'Windows XP', 'DiffDSPBrd', '8.00.01_uflx (P7)', '8.0', '2015-06-11 11:15:33');
INSERT INTO TBL_TESTER_INFO(tester_name, operating_system , version, board_name , config , date_modified ) VALUES ('UFLEX-06', 'Windows XP', '123DSPBrd', '8.00.01_uflx (P7)', '26.0', '2015-06-11 11:15:33');
INSERT INTO TBL_TESTER_INFO(tester_name, operating_system , version, board_name , config , date_modified ) VALUES ('UFLEX-06', 'Windows XP', 'V1r12alDSPBrd', '8.00.01_uflx (P7)', '56.0', '2015-06-11 11:15:33');
INSERT INTO TBL_TESTER_INFO(tester_name, operating_system , version, board_name , config , date_modified ) VALUES ('UFLEX-06', 'Windows XP', 'VMamaBrd', '8.00.01_uflx (P7)', '52.0', '2015-06-11 11:15:33');
INSERT INTO TBL_TESTER_INFO(tester_name, operating_system , version, board_name , config , date_modified ) VALUES ('UFLEX-06', 'Windows XP', 'ONSPBrd', '8.00.01_uflx (P7)', '56.0', '2015-06-11 11:15:33');
INSERT INTO TBL_TESTER_INFO(tester_name, operating_system , version, board_name , config , date_modified ) VALUES ('UFLEX-06', 'Windows XP', 'bankaiPBrd', '8.00.01_uflx (P7)', '66.0', '2015-06-11 11:15:33');
```

So the question is how do I iterate and then print according to how many indexes are in the hash `$details{slot}` where by `$details{slot}` and `$details{board_name}` would be printed according to their indexes?

I understand that I would have to create another for loop inside the current one I have. However, most solutions are for hashes that only contain one value so that's why it doesn't cater to my needs.

EDIT:

(Note: This dump shows only the latest `board_name` and `slot`)

```
{
    board_name => "Virtualabc"
    igxl_vn => "9.0.0_abc"
    op_sys => "Windows"
    slot => "66.0"
    tester_name => "UNFEK-02"
}
```

EDIT 2:

I've edited my script where by I have declared `slot` and `board_name` into arrays as suggested by @shivams.

```
push @{ $details{slot} }, [$1];
push @{ $details{board_name} }, [$2];
```

Now as suggested by Dmitry's answer(first part), I am getting the reference to the array only. Here is the output:

```
INSERT INTO TBL_TESTER_INFO(tester_name, operating_system , version, board_name , config , date_modified ) VALUES ('UFLEX-06', 'Windows XP', 'ARRAY(0x1d2fb98) [0]', '8.00.01_uflx (P7)', 'ARRAY(0x1d40288) [0]', '2015-06-11 15:18:37');
INSERT INTO TBL_TESTER_INFO(tester_name, operating_system , version, board_name , config , date_modified ) VALUES ('UFLEX-06', 'Windows XP', 'ARRAY(0x1d2fb98) [1]', '8.00.01_uflx (P7)', 'ARRAY(0x1d40288) [1]', '2015-06-11 15:18:37');
INSERT INTO TBL_TESTER_INFO(tester_name, operating_system , version, board_name , config , date_modified ) VALUES ('UFLEX-06', 'Windows XP', 'ARRAY(0x1d2fb98) [2]', '8.00.01_uflx (P7)', 'ARRAY(0x1d40288) [2]', '2015-06-11 15:18:37');
INSERT INTO TBL_TESTER_INFO(tester_name, operating_system , version, board_name , config , date_modified ) VALUES ('UFLEX-06', 'Windows XP', 'ARRAY(0x1d2fb98) [3]', '8.00.01_uflx (P7)', 'ARRAY(0x1d40288) [3]', '2015-06-11 15:18:37');
INSERT INTO TBL_TESTER_INFO(tester_name, operating_system , version, board_name , config , date_modified ) VALUES ('UFLEX-06', 'Windows XP', 'ARRAY(0x1d2fb98) [4]', '8.00.01_uflx (P7)', 'ARRAY(0x1d40288) [4]', '2015-06-11 15:18:37');
INSERT INTO TBL_TESTER_INFO(tester_name, operating_system , version, board_name , config , date_modified ) VALUES ('UFLEX-06', 'Windows XP', 'ARRAY(0x1d2fb98) [5]', '8.00.01_uflx (P7)', 'ARRAY(0x1d40288) [5]', '2015-06-11 15:18:37');
INSERT INTO TBL_TESTER_INFO(tester_name, operating_system , version, board_name , config , date_modified ) VALUES ('UFLEX-06', 'Windows XP', 'ARRAY(0x1d2fb98) [6]', '8.00.01_uflx (P7)', 'ARRAY(0x1d40288) [6]', '2015-06-11 15:18:37');
INSERT INTO TBL_TESTER_INFO(tester_name, operating_system , version, board_name , config , date_modified ) VALUES ('UFLEX-06', 'Windows XP', 'ARRAY(0x1d2fb98) [7]', '8.00.01_uflx (P7)', 'ARRAY(0x1d40288) [7]', '2015-06-11 15:18:37');
INSERT INTO TBL_TESTER_INFO(tester_name, operating_system , version, board_name , config , date_modified ) VALUES ('UFLEX-06', 'Windows XP', 'ARRAY(0x1d2fb98) [8]', '8.00.01_uflx (P7)', 'ARRAY(0x1d40288) [8]', '2015-06-11 15:18:37');
INSERT INTO TBL_TESTER_INFO(tester_name, operating_system , version, board_name , config , date_modified ) VALUES ('UFLEX-06', 'Windows XP', 'ARRAY(0x1d2fb98) [9]', '8.00.01_uflx (P7)', 'ARRAY(0x1d40288) [9]', '2015-06-11 15:18:37');
INSERT INTO TBL_TESTER_INFO(tester_name, operating_system , version, board_name , config , date_modified ) VALUES ('UFLEX-06', 'Windows XP', 'ARRAY(0x1d2fb98) [10]', '8.00.01_uflx (P7)', 'ARRAY(0x1d40288) [10]', '2015-06-11 15:18:37');
INSERT INTO TBL_TESTER_INFO(tester_name, operating_system , version, board_name , config , date_modified ) VALUES ('UFLEX-06', 'Windows XP', 'ARRAY(0x1d2fb98) [11]', '8.00.01_uflx (P7)', 'ARRAY(0x1d40288) [11]', '2015-06-11 15:18:37');
```

How do I get the exact value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not actually need to loop through `keys %details`. I take it, you have built the `%details` hash based on Borodin's suggestion from [Extracting data from log file into Perl hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30749382/extracting-data-from-log-file-into-perl-hash). In this case what you have is not actually an array of hashes but rather a single hash `%details` containing two lists in it (among some other scalar values).

In order to prepare the desired set of insert statements from it you should iterate through `%details`'s sublists only. The `%details`'s scalar fields should be accessed directly:

```
for (my $i = 0; $i < @{$details{slot}}; $i++) {
    print
        "INSERT INTO TesterDeviceMatrix.TBL_TESTER_INFO"
        ."(tester_name, operating_system , version, board_name , config , date_modified ) "
        ."VALUES ('$details{tester_name}', '$details{op_sys}', '$details{board_name}[$i]', "
        ."'$details{igxl_vn}', '$details{slot}[$i]', '$timestamp');\n";
}
```

[Here](https://ideone.com/OcHmRR) is a test script illustrating the said above.

UPDATE following EDIT 2:

Change

```
push @{ $details{slot} }, [$1];
push @{ $details{board_name} }, [$2];
```

to

```
push @{ $details{slot} }, $1;
push @{ $details{board_name} }, $2;
```

Pushing `[$var]` (i.e. a scalar variable with square brackets) into an array would populate the array with one-element sub-arrays containing this single scalar value each. This is because `[$var]` constructs a reference to an array containing the single element `$var`. All you actually need instead is to push the scalar value itself.

P.S.

Consider using parametrized queries instead of hardcoded ones.

Comment: Ahh yes I have built on it according to Borodin's suggestion. This iterating of using `for` is what I have thought of and come closest to. I tried your way but I'm getting an error saying "Can't use string ("66.0") as an ARRAY ref while "strict refs" in use at exTester.pl line 51." where by line 51 is pointing to the `for` statement.

Comment: Well, you seem to have a scalar value when an array reference expected. Could you please post a dump of your `%details` hash (see `Dumper()` call in https://ideone.com/ITGear for example)?

Comment: Rather to `$details{slot}[$i][0]`. This is because `push @{ $details{slot} }, [$1];` populates the `@{ $details{slot} }` not with the desired scalars but with one-element arrays containing these scalars. I believe you can change your `push @{ $details{slot} }, [$1];` to `push @{ $details{slot} }, $1;` (notice, there're no square brackets in the amended version). In this case you should be able to use `$details{slot}[$i]` without changes.

Comment: https://ideone.com/mqy17v This is the full program if you need to see it, together with the dump. Tried it out with your answer, getting a `Global symbol "@details_array" requires explicit package name at exTester.pl line 52.
Execution of exTester.pl aborted due to compilation errors.`

Comment: `@details_array` is out of scope now since you're using a plain hash (perhapsh you'd wish to change the question header to something like "iterating trough an array nested into a hash" for clarity). Here: https://ideone.com/eT8WPD is the updated version which works fine on my test data. The only change I've done is removing square brackets from `push` (lines 30 & 31)

Comment: Ahh now I understand. And yes this is what I wanted. Thank you, you can edit your post too to follow the one you have done in the link in case anyone has the same problem. Once again, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach my $key(keys %details) {
 if (ref($key)  eq 'ARRAY') {
   foreach $key2 (@$key) {
      PRINT STATEMENT
   }
 }
 else {
  PRINT STATEMENT
 }
}
```

In this way when there is array in hash your code will loop on that array through inner `foreach` loop and if not it will go to `else`. Also now how you want to use values i totally upon you.

Comment: Hmm I see, +1 but my problem still remains the same. I have to print every value in `$details{slot}` but now I am only getting the latest value. Now it displays nothing if I add the print statement inside.

Comment: Try and only print values on screen and not on file. This is also giving you latest values. Also can you use `Dumper` on your hash and give that output.

Comment: Then is there any other way like `dump`? Cause on screen I used dump and it does display every value in the key.

Comment: use `Data::Dumper`. I just want that hash so i can try it out.

Comment: From what dump you are showing `slot`  does not have `array` as value but simple `string` and in output you will get only that string.

Comment: Edited in my question.

Comment: Yeah just tried it, it doesn't seem to detect any arrays present. Instead it does the statement it the `else` which I printed as error. Also, the error prints out five times, which means it is only printing out the hashes in `%details`, not according to the values in `details{slot}`.